# Do I have to delete the object behind a pointer before assigning a new one in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, new-operator, delete-operator

Consider the following situation in C++:

```
void Light::setColor(Color* &color, ColorType type)
{
    color = new Color(type);
}
```

Do I have to delete the value that might has been stored at pointer "color" before, since C++ does not delete such objects itself? I have tried different combinations:

```
delete *&color;
delete &color;
delete &*color;
```

Nothing works.

Comment: Why are you passing a reference to a pointer... just pass a reference, then this entire question is irrelevant.

Comment: What you mean by "nothing works"? Have you tried `delete color;`?

Comment: Shouldn't `setColor` be doing something to a member of `Light`? Do you have a member `color` as well as an argument `color`?

Comment: I highly suggest you read this [Guru of the week](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/)

Comment: It seems setColor() is a private method. Use it like setColor(Color* color, ColorType type) {  if ( color ) then color.setType(type) else  color = new Color(type). This means you should create a setType function for color which is better than deleting and creating the object again with a different type.

Comment: Thank you, @cageman! That's a really good question! Why the hell do I want to delete and then re-instantiate it, if I could simply modify it. Even though it is no answer to my question, it solves my problem. Many thanks! :-D @0x499602D2 With "nothing works" I meant that VS2013 always throws errors if I try those combinations.

Answer (score 1):

```
 delete color;
```

Will work and learn how to spell

Answer (score 1):

If you have just this function you cannot say whether or not `color` was allocated beforehand.
You may have a `nullptr` or a valid pointer in both case `delete color;` will work (because there is no need to test for `nullptr` when calling `delete`).

But you may get something wrong (a non initialized pointer or even a pointer to a object allocated on the stack) and in that case delete will fail.

I would recommand that you use `std::shared_ptr<Color>` it will solve your ownership problems.

```
void Light::setColor(std::shared_ptr<Color>& color, ColorType type)
{    
    color = std::make_shared<Color>(type);
}
```

Or better:

```
std::shared_ptr<Color> Light::setColor(ColorType type)
{    
   return std::make_shared<Color>(type);
}
```

But by convention, a method starting with "set" is supposed to assign something to a internal member. `createColor` would be better.

Comment: Please read [Herb Sutter's article on Smart Pointer Parameters](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/)

Comment: @Mgetz See my edit. And btw it a ref over a `std::shared_ptr` so no useless inc/dec.

Answer (score 1):

This is a more general question regarding pointers.

When you have a pointer to an object, you are referencing a part of memory. When you delete that memory, it gets freed.

So, if you do:

```
color = new Color(...);
```

you are allocating a piece of memory with the contents of an object of type Color.

Thus, you can just delete that memory through that pointer:

```
delete color;
```

Now, in this case, *color wouldn't be too useful: you are referencing the MEMORY that the object occupies, which isn't what you want.

Let's take another example: if you have a simple object, say an array of characters:

```
char *str = new char[200];
```

then the pointer `str` points to the instantiated object, and `*str` to the memory contents that the object occupies. In that case, the pointer itself isn't what you want: you are interested in the actual data stored in that memory block (i.e. a string of characters).

Thus, `delete[] str;` will delete the memory block that str points to. `delete[] *str;` won't make much sense.

so, if we try this with printf():

```
char *str = new char[200];
strcpy(str, "test");
printf("The variable's contents are: %s", str); // will print the string itself
printf("The variable's address is: %p", str);   // will print the address of the string in memory
```

Here's a useful link regarding pointers, to clear some things out:
http://courses.washington.edu/css342/zander/css332/pointers.html

Comment: I fixed the `delete[]`, but bringing up arrays makes pointers more confusing.